# Sorting object array with date and a string angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I have an employment record object array, let's say it has this record:

```
var records = [
        {name: "Sample",  monthTo: "NOV", yearTo: "1960"},
        {name: "Sample2",  monthTo: "JAN", yearTo: "2016"},
        {name: "Sample3",  monthTo: "DEC", yearTo: "2017"},
    ];
```

If I want to sort this in the most recent I can do:

```
function sortEmpHistoryByLatest(){

        records.sort(function(a,b) {


                var aDate = new Date(a.getYearTo()+"-"+a.getMonthTo()+"-01").getDate();
                var bDate = new Date(b.getYearTo()+"-"+b.getMonthTo()+"-01").getDate();

                return aDate - bDate

        });
    }
```

This works fine, but what if I have `Present` as record and not a month or year format? Let's say:

```
var records2 = [
        {name: "Sample",  monthTo: "NOV", yearTo: "1960"},
        {name: "Sample2",  monthTo: "Present", yearTo: "Present"},
        {name: "Sample3",  monthTo: "DEC", yearTo: "2017"},
    ];
```

How can I sort this with the `Present` being first in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split you array into two arrays - one only with dates and another with "Present" marks. Then only sort the first array and merge them.

You can split them using next code:

```
var records_with_dates = records.filter(function(record){return record.monthTo!=='Present';});
var sorted_records_with_dates = records_with_dates.sort(// your sort func);
var present_records = records.filter(function(record){return record.monthTo==='Present';});

var sorted_records = present_records.concat(sorted_records_with_dates);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as shown below: by replacing precent with current year and month.

And you can checkout working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cUjAGaYwOPZsIaM7tvqA?p=preview)

```
var sorted;
var months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
var today = new Date();
var mm = today.getMonth();
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var mmStr = months[mm];
console.log('currentMonth:' + mmStr)

function sortEmpHistoryByLatest() {
  sorted = records.sort(function(a, b) {

    var monthA = a.monthTo == "Present" ? mm : months.indexOf(a.monthTo);
    var yearA = a.yearTo == "Present" ? yyyy : a.yearTo;
    var monthB = b.monthTo == "Present" ? mm : months.indexOf(b.monthTo);
    var yearB = b.yearTo == "Present" ? yyyy : b.yearTo;

    var aDate = new Date(yearA, monthA);
    var bDate = new Date(yearB, monthB); 
    console.log('A'+aDate+' yearMonth'+yearA+''+monthA);
    console.log('B'+aDate+' yearMonth'+yearB+''+monthB)
    return bDate - aDate; //Ascending  order
    //return aDate - bDate;//for Descending  order
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi @yassi, Is it answered your question?